# Qmake: separate dir for objects: how to handle equally named objects

Tags: qt, qmake

I have specified a separate dir for objects (`OBJECTS_DIR=$$PWD/build/qt/objs`). My project contains of several sub-dirs, where all sub-projects use that same dir for objects. (That is done as described [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QMake-top-level-srcdir-and-builddir).)

Now it might happen that two separate sub-projects generate the same object file (e.g. there is `sub1/foo.cpp` and `sub2/foo.cpp`). How can I handle that? Can I somehow tell Qmake to keep the project-directory-structure in `OBJECTS_DIR`?

Comment: Why exactly do you set OBJECTS_DIR? If it's about not polluting the source tree: QMake supports out-of-source builds. Otherwise you'll have to set OBJECTS_DIR in each .pro file separately, to point to e.g. $$PWD/build/qt/objs/foo, $$PWD/build/qt/objs/bar, etc.

Comment: When specifying `OBJECTS_DIR` and `DESTDIR`, isn't that an out-of-source build? Or what do you mean?

Comment: I mean creating a separate directory, and calling `qmake $pathtosourcedir` from there (what Qt Creator does by default). Ideally, that doesn't require any .pro file changes at all.

Comment: I'm interested too in this question. I'm trying to port to qmake a Makefile that handles source files with same name in different dirs, which produces objects with the same name and links them using specific recipes.